# How to find an array of all the words in json that can be made by rearranging these letters(Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. How do I write a function that takes a find method that accepts a lower case and the find should return an array of all the words in dic.json that can be made by rearranging these letters. So if I input `"ab"` then the output should be `["ab", "ba"]` from the JSON file below.

dic.json

```
[
"ab",
"ba",
"abc",
"acb",
"bac",
"bca",
"cab",
"cba"
]
```

This is what have so far

I used File read to access the JSON file and I have a function that can find permutations but I am not sure how to connect the two functions.

````
class LetterLocater
  def get_file_contents
    return File.read('dictionary.json').split
  end

   def permutation(letters)
    return [''] if letters.empty?

    chrs = letters.chars
    (0...letters.size).flat_map { |i|
      chr, rest = letters[i], letters[0...i] + letters[i+1..-1]
      permutation(rest).map { |sub|
        chr + sub
      }
    }
  end
end

a = LetterLocater.new
puts a.permutation(gets.chomp)                                                                                                                                       ```
````

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you able to read the file and ect.

Comment: Thank you for asking, I added what I have so far.

Comment: Instead of reading the file as text, load it as JSON. `JSON.load(File.open('dictionary.json'))`. This will result in a Ruby Array. Then you can work with that.

Comment: Are the words in the dictionary and the string `ab` and `abc` only examples? Like could the dictionary be `["car", "dog"]` and the string `"acr"`? Or do you always expect the dictionary to contain all permutations of the string anyway?

Comment: @spickermann the JSON file has thousands of letters so if I input ```car``` from the JSON file I should get all rearranging possible letters so like ```[car, cra, acr, arc, rca, rac]

Comment: What is the point of searching for all permutations on the input files and having an input file in the first place when all you want to do is to return all permutations of the second input string? Just calling `"letters.permutation"` should then always return the exact same output without the need to read the fils and compare its content.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating all permutations for various inputs, you could also group the words from the dictionary by sorting their letters:

```
def sorted(str)
  str.chars.sort.join
end

# assume this was read from the JSON file
dict = %w[ab ba abc acb bac bca cab cba]

lookup_hash = dict.group_by { |word| sorted(word) }
#=> {
#     "ab"  => ["ab", "ba"],
#     "abc" => ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
#   }
```

Although this calculation can be quite expensive for larger dictionaries, you only have to do it *once*. (you could even store the hash to disk and only update when your dictionary changes)

After creating the hash, it's almost trivial to find the permutations. You just have to fetch the values for the sorted input:

```
input = gets.chomp
puts lookup_hash[sorted(input)]
```

This will be much faster than generating all permutation each time.

Comment: can't use this method if I have thousands letters in the JSON file, how would I include the json file in that case?

Comment: @yadel did you try? Transforming an array with thousands of entries should still be quite fast. And since it’s  a one-time operation, you can save the optimized lookup hash to file.

Comment: You could alternatively write `def sorted(str); str.each_char.tally; end`.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby there is already [`Array#permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation) that you can use to calculate all possible words.

```
letters = "ab" # example
permutations = letters.split(//).permutation.map(&:join)
#=> ["ab", "ba"]
```

And then there is ['Array#&'](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-26) that returns only elements from an array that are present in another array.

```
words = ["ab", "ba", "abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
words & permutations
#=> ["ab", "ba"]
```

And you can use `JSON.load(File.open('dictionary.json'))` to load the JSON file into a Ruby array – as Schwern already wrote in his comment.

Now let's combine all these methods into one class

```
require 'json'

class LetterLocater
  attr_reader :words

  def initialize(dictionary)
    @words = JSON.load(File.open('dictionary.json'))
  end

  def permutation(letters)
    permutations = letters.split(//).permutation.map(&:join)
    words & permutations
  end
end

ll = LetterLocater.new('dictionary.json')

ll.permutation('ab')
#=> ["ab", "ba"]
ll.permutation('abc')
#=> ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do it without using the build-in method permutation? can it be done with a find method?

Comment: Why? What do you want to avoid using a method that does exactly what you need? Why this special requirement? Is this some kind of homework?

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_permutations_in_array(arr, str)
  chars = str.chars.sort
  arr.inject([]) do |res, word|
    res << word if word.size == str.size && word.chars.sort == chars
    res
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @scorix where did use the json file?

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**

I have assumed that the task is *one-off*, in the sense that the task is to be performed for a single word and a given dictionary, not for possibly many words and the same dictionary.

**Approach**

I propose that three tests be used to determine if each dictionary word is formed by permuting the letters in the given word:

- reject the dictionary word if its length differs from that of the given word
- if the above test fails, reject the dictionary word if it begins with a string `s` where it has been determined that no word beginning with `s` can be formed by permuting the letters of the given word
- if the above test fails, each character in the dictionary is examined in sequence until a character is found that is not present in the given word or whose count in the dictionary word exceeds the count of the same character in the given word, in which case the dictionary word can be rejected

If none of the above tests succeeds we may conclude that the dictionary word can be formed by permuting the letters of the given word.

Note that, in the third test above, if the dictionary word `w` was rejected when its character at index `i` was examined we may conclude that no dictionary word that begins with `s = w[0,i]` can be formed by permuting the characters of the given word, which is the basis for the second test.

**Code**

```
def find_em(word, dict)
  word_len = word.length
  ltr_cnt = word.each_char.tally
  prefix = ''
  dict.select do |w|
    next false if w.length != word_len ||
      (prefix.length > 0 && w.start_with?(prefix))
    prefix = ''
    lc = ltr_cnt.dup
    ltrs_used = 0
    w.each_char do |c|
      prefix << c
      break unless lc.key?(c) && lc[c] > 0
      lc[c] -= 1
      ltrs_used += 1
    end
    if ltrs_used == word_len
      prefix = ''
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
word = "aab"
```

```
dict = [
  "aaa", "aab", "ab", "aba", "abb", "aca", "acad", "acb", "acc", 
  "acd", "ace", "ba", "bac", "bca", "bcc", "caa", "cab", "cbb"
]
```

Being a "dictionary", I assume the words of `dict` are ordered lexicographically, but if that is not the case the first step is to sort the given array words to produce `dict`.

```
find_em(word, dict)
  #=> ["aab", "aba"]
```

**Explanation**

For the example just given the method processes each word in the dictionary in as indicated by the following:

```
"aaa", "aab", "ab", "aba", "abb",  "aca", "acad", "acb", "acc", 
   c     m      s     m       c      n       s      r      r
"acd", "ace", "ba", "bac", "bca", "bcc", "caa", "cab", "cbb"
  r      r      s      n     n      r     n      r      r
```

- "aaa" is rejected (signified by "c", for "count"), when the third character is examined, because `word` contains only two "a"'s (which is why "c" is shown under the third "a")
- "aab" is matched (signified by "m") because its letters are a permutation of the letters of `word`
- "ab" is rejected because the length of the word is not the same as the length of `word`
- "aba" is matched
- "abb" is rejected when the second "b" is examined because there are too many "b"'s
- "aca" is rejected when "c" is examined because `word` does not contain "c" (indicated by the "n" under the "c")
- "acad" is rejected because it is the wrong size
- "acb", "acc", "acd", "ace" are all rejected because we know from the processing of "aca" that no words starting with "ac" can match (indicated by "r" for "repeat")
- "ba" is the wrong size
- "bac" is rejected because `word` does not contain "c"
- "bca" does not begin "bac" so we examine each letter from the start of the word until we find "c", which is not contained in `word` so we reject the word
- "bcc" is rejected because we know from examining "bca" that no words starting with "bc" can match
- "caa" is rejected because `word` does not contain "c"
- "cab" and "cbb" are rejected because we know from examining "caa" that no words starting with "c" can match

---

To better understand details of the calculations one might execute the method after having salted it with `puts` statements. For example, one might execute the following modification.

```
def find_em(word, dict)
  word_len = word.length
  ltr_cnt = word.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  prefix = ''
  dict.select do |w|
    puts "w=#{w}, prefix=#{prefix}"
    next false if w.length != word_len ||
      (prefix.length > 0 && w.start_with?(prefix))
    prefix = ''
    lc = ltr_cnt.dup
    ltrs_used = 0
    w.each_char do |c|
      puts "  prefix=#{prefix}, lc=#{lc}"
      prefix << c
      break unless lc.key?(c) && lc[c] > 0
      lc[c] -= 1
      ltrs_used += 1
    end
    puts "  for w = #{w} prefix = #{prefix}"
    if ltrs_used == word_len
      puts "  w = '#{w}' a match"
      prefix = ''
      true
    else
      puts "  w = '#{w} *not* a match"
    false
    end
  end
end
```

**Alternative when `word` is relatively short**

If the number of unique permutations of the letters of `word` is relatively small we could generate each word that is formed by a unique permutation of the characters in `word` and then use [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) to perform a binary search to determine if that word is in the dictionary:

```
def present?(word, dict)
  dict.bsearch { |w| w >= word } == word
end
```

```
word.chars.permutation.map(&:join).uniq.select { |w| present?(w, dict) }
  #=> ["aab", "aba"]
```